# ajax send file and variable to php

Tags: php, ajax, file, jquery, upload

I'm using an ajax call to upload a file, handled by PHP. The file should be placed in a specific directory based on a jquery variable. I can get the file to upload, but cannot pass the variable along with the file. PHP reports an undefined index error.

Ajax code:

```
var fd = new FormData();    
fd.append( 'file', document.getElementById('select').files[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(e){
        // some code here
    }
});
```

I tried changing the data property to "fd+'&myVar='+myVar, however PHP cannot parse the data correctly and returns undefined index error for both the $_FILES['file'] variable as well as the $_POST['myVar'] variable.

How can I send both the file and a variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need another form field, call fd.append a second time:

```
fd.append('file', document.getElementById('select').files[0]);
fd.append('myVar',myVar);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#append%28%29) values other than files to a formdata object.

```
var fd = new FormData();    
fd.append( 'file', document.getElementById('select').files[0]);
fd.append( 'myVar', myVar);
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(e){
        // some code here
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Refer to [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) jQuery API Documentation.

It is clearly stated that `data` should be an object with key-value pairs representing data accepted by server-side script. Whatever, not sure why jQuery seems to not accept your data. Maybe you should try this out manually.

Since your `test.php` accepts `POST` data as `myVar` your jQuery Ajax configuration should probably look like

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        myVar: document.getElementById('select').files[0]
    },
    success: function(e){
    // some code here
    }
});
```